# DOJO Full screen using HTML API

Tags: html, dojo

I am using [HTML5 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) to view my div tag(which displays DOJO table). When I place an img tag, I am able to toggle full screen but when I place DOJO, full screen is not toggled. Some one please help....